# How to call an object method by Proxy in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have the class:

```
class Course {
  constructor(name) {
    this._name = name;
  }

  getName() {
    return this._name;
  }
}
```

I want to create a proxy around class Course, that will return only non-private fields and methods:

```
const handlers = {
  get: (target, prop, reciever) => {
    if (prop in reciever && prop[0] !== '_' ) {
      if (typeof reciever[prop] === 'function') {
        return reciever[prop].apply(reciever);
      } else {
        return reciever[prop];
      }
    } else {
      throw new Error('problem');
    }
  }
}

const protect = (obj) => {
  return new Proxy(obj, handlers);
}
```

But when i call object method:

```
const protectedCourse = protect(new Course('Test'));
console.log(protectedCourse.getName()); // The expected result is - "Test"
```

I got the error:

```
  if (prop in reciever && prop[0] !== '_' ) {
    ^

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Object.get (file:///usr/src/app/protect.js:37:5)
    at Object.get (file:///usr/src/app/protect.js:38:26)
    at Object.get (file:///usr/src/app/protect.js:38:26)
    at Object.get (file:///usr/src/app/protect.js:38:26)
    at Object.get (file:///usr/src/app/protect.js:38:26)
    at Object.get (file:///usr/src/app/protect.js:38:26)
    at Object.get (file:///usr/src/app/protect.js:38:26)
    at Object.get (file:///usr/src/app/protect.js:38:26)
    at Object.get (file:///usr/src/app/protect.js:38:26)
    at Object.get (file:///usr/src/app/protect.js:38:26)
```

How to call object method without infinity recursion in the handler of Proxy?

Comment: What's the actual error you get?

Comment: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should access the property on `target`, which is the original object, instead of `receiver` which is the `Proxy`. Additionally, use `bind` instead of `apply` or `call` to return a function with the `this` value set.

Note that what you are trying to achieve with a `Proxy` can be done with [private class fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields).

```js
class Course {
  constructor(name) {
    this._name = name;
  }

  getName() {
    return this._name;
  }
}

const handlers = {
  get: (target, prop, receiver) => {
    if (prop in target && prop[0] !== '_') {
      if (typeof target[prop] === 'function') {
        return target[prop].bind(target);
      } else {
        return target[prop];
      }
    } else {
      throw new Error('problem');
    }
  }
}

const protect = (obj) => {
  return new Proxy(obj, handlers);
}

const protectedCourse = protect(new Course('Test'));
console.log(protectedCourse.getName());
```